# Pantomime = outdated. Sending and receiving mail framework

Tags: objective-c, frameworks

As I found out, Pantomime framework is outdated. I believe the newest realize came out in 2007. I'm getting a lot of compiling errors because of this. From the top of my head, I got about 1000 errors. So it's probably going to take a while to convert it to a newer version.

What is another sending/receiving mail framework that is up to date?

I'm new to objective-c and programming in general so take it easy... :)

Elijah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it, but a quick Google points me to the [MailCore](http://www.mronge.com/code/) framework, which seems to be a bit more recent, and there appears to be an [iPhone port](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/) that is actively developed.

Comment: The project moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/mronge/MailCore).

Answer (score 0):

There's also c-client!

"Sending mail on Snow Leopard using the c-client API",

http://blog.loudhush.ro/2009/10/sending-mail-on-snow-leopard-using-c.html

Comment: Please summarize the contents of the link; simply posting a link is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Outdated refer to NSSharingService since Mac OS X 10.8.