# Sending a mail through a forgotten password selector

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, email

I'm developing an user interface for OS X and I don't find any convenient method to automatically send an email when the user uses the "Forgotten Password" button I provided.

I went through this post : [Send email from Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461648/send-email-from-cocoa)

But the comments left made me think that this is not the proper way to do it, I'm new to Objective-C and Cocoa programming and I don't really understood it.

I want the mail to be sent to contain a specific subject and a written text with the new password I generated.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks.

Comment: Will your app be sandboxed?

Comment: It's not an app, it's a software for OSX, so far, I don't think it is sandboxed (I'm just adding a plugin on this software)

Comment: Apps on OS X may be sandboxed. If they are shipped from the Mac App Store, they are required to be. If you already have the plugin running within the app in some form it is not sandboxed.

Comment: it is the same question and the answers still apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461648/send-email-from-cocoa

Answer (score 0):

Since your plugin is not running in sandboxed mode, you can use the AppleScript solution presented in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5535198/453082

Using AppleScript is definitely one of the 'proper' ways of doing things, even though it is falling out of use now that many apps are shipping sandboxed (which prevents using AppleScript to control other apps).